# Grails 2.0: MissingPropertyException when setting attribute on Session

Tags: unit-testing, session, grails, controller

Since upgrading to Grails 2.0.0 from 2.0.0.RC1 There's some really strange behaviour in my controller when setting the user attribute on the session.

My test is under integration and when running `grails --integration test-app` or from an IDE all tests pass but when running `grails test-app` **with the unit tests first, it fails.**

I am simply setting the user on the session in my UserController.login() action:

```
session.user = user
```

My test looks like that:

```
params.userName = testUser1.userName  // some user domain instance
params.password = testUser1.password
controller.doLogin()
assert null != session.user
```

When running `grails test-app` I receive the following error on the `session.user=user` line:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: user for class: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsHttpSession
Possible solutions: new
```

Replacing the controller code with the following works:

```
session.setAttribute('user',user)
```

and the test with:

```
assert null != session.getAttribute('user')
```

As mentioned above, this only happens when running the full test suite. If running `--integration` it's fine. `run-app` is ok too.

A bug?

Regards

Jonas

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem. I am using Grails 2.0.1

One thing I notice is that, the failing tests have some setup using metaClass, like:

```
controller.metaClass.message = {args -> "mockMessage"}
```

After removing that line, the test will run pass the part that access session attributes. But the tests will not work when reaching the point that call message()

Comment: any chance you could do `controller.metaClass.message = null` to remove the metaclass when you need to, and then put it back in if the order of your operations requires it?